# "No root file system is defined error" when installing

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, partitioning, wubi, ubiquity

i tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 with CD but it is not detecting my Windows Installation (Windows XP SP2) and I don't want to do partioning manually.

I then tried to install Ubuntu 12.10 using Wubi. Then I rebooted as it asked but after some time a screen appeared saying `No root file system is defined`. `Please correct this from the partitioning screen`. But the drop down box is empty.

I've tried installing Wubi in `C:\` and `D:\` but there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I've linked you to another answer that describes what causes this problem. If you fix it using those instructions, then you'll be able to do a normal dual boot, as well as Wubi. The same problem is affecting both.

If you run `wubi.exe` standalone (with no CD in the computer, or ISO) then it will probably work as it doesn't use `ubiquity` (the Ubuntu installer, which is what is kicking out that error via the `parted` program). It will have to download a 500MB preinstalled disk-image in that case.

I'm adding this answer only because it's often possible to bypass the error by avoiding `ubiquity` and `parted`. But ideally, if you want a proper dual boot you'll investigate the real problem and correct the partitioning problem.

Comment: my pc has un allocated space .can i install ubuntu 12.10 in un-allocated space by using ubuntu-cd.or my os is not dected by ubuntu installer.and how can i make ubuntu installer to identify my present os

Comment: If the installer detects your other operating system - otherwise that 'unallocated' space is actually allocated and will be overwritten. Did you figure out the problem yet?

Comment: i cheked for all errors that may be possibel as given on ubuntu site and wubi site but i found that all is fine but the above problem   repets

Comment: if i manually partion using ubuntu 12.10 cd will it allocate space for ubuntu on c drive?? i asked this as i did not found any option there it is just giving total disc as one

Comment: No - anything you do will destroy what's already there. If it can't detect the other partitons/operating system, then it will overwrite them.

Comment: Please link to the output of the bootinfoscript. Thanks http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net/

Comment: finalllllllyyyyyyy  got success ubuntu gave an option to install along with windows xp i this may be because i had formater my c drive and re installee xp and the i installed ubuntu12.10

Comment: @ramkiran Great! Enjoy!

Comment: my ubuntu 12.10 is not showing icons on left it is showing only folders on desktop i dont understand what 2 do pls help...  i am afraid if i install ubuntu 13.04 all the present applications will be deleated may be due to compatabity issus pls help me...

Comment: @ramkiran Please create a new question describing your problem since it is different to the one answered here. Thanks

Comment: ok bcbc it had some how solved above comment by installing gnome through software center.pls.. try 2 solve this is below problem...  http://askubuntu.com/questions/286154/problem-with-lxde-having-ubuntu-12-10-with-gnome